# Remove particular item from list with all its duplicate in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, duplicates

I want to delete a particular element from the list with all its duplicates(not deleting duplicates of other elements), I can do it manually using multiple for loops but please suggest any builtin function if exist.

```
l1 = [some elements with duplicates]
for i in l1
  count = count.l1(i)# Counted duplicates of i
  #some stuff with count
  ## here want to delete the element at the ith position with all its duplicates
```

for example, I have a list [2,3,4,6,2,4,3,2]  # which could be unknown
I counted the duplicate of 2 and deleted 2 with all its duplicate
duplicate_count_of_i=3,
some stuff,
remove the element with all its duplicates
updated list [3,4,6,4,3]
Thank You for your time, have a nice day.

Comment: On what condition remove the element ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the pseudocode here since `count.l1` does nothing, but why not just `[x for x in list if x != your_obj]`? Instead of `[some elements with duplicates]`, you could actually show the elements and produce a [mcve] which leaves a lot less up in the air. Also showing the before/after example makes it much easier to tell what you need.

Comment: create set of the list.

Comment: Note that any set-based solution requires the elements of the list to be hashable (though commonly that is the case).

Answer (score 2):

If you want just unique elements, use a set:

```
l1 = [some elements with duplicates] # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
l1 = list(set(l1))                   # [1, 2, 3]
```

But if you want duplicate element to be totally removed you can do

```
l1 = [some elements with duplicates]            # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
l1 = [elt for elt in l1 if l1.count(elt) == 1]  # [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Python Sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) to do the job. It will never take any duplicate items in your list. And after that you can convert it to list

**CODE**

```
l1 = ["apple", "banana", "apple"]
li2 = list(set(l1))

print(li2)

# >>> ['banana', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not exactly understood what did you mean by "particular item from list with all its duplicate ".

i) Do you mean all the occurrences of that item
ii) Or all the duplicates of that item

**For Case 1:**

You can use while loop to remove all the instances of an element from the list.

```
>>> l1 =  [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6]    
>>> element_to_remove = 5
>>>
>>> while element_to_remove in l1:
...    l1.remove(element_to_remove)
>>> l1
[1,2,3,3,4,4,6,6]
```

**For Case 2:**

```
>>> l1 =  [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6]    
>>> element_to_remove = 5
>>>
>>> while l1.count(element_to_remove) > 1: #removing all the duplicates
...    l1.remove(element_to_remove)
>>> l1
[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6]
```